# How to manage endless variations of a question with LUIS?

Tags: azure-language-understanding

The bot will ask the following:

*-"How many people will stay in the apartment? And how many rooms do the apartment have?"*

If the user replies the following:

*-"3 people will stay in my 2 bedroom apartment."*

Then it´s easy to extract the information I need by the use of 1 Simple Entity with 2 Roles (AmountOfPeople and RoomsInApartment).

However, the user can reply to the questions in many different ways. For e.g:

*-"3 people and one dog will stay in my 2 bedroom apartment."*

Or

*-"3 people will stay in my friend´s 2 bedroom cottage."*

Or

*-"3 people will not stay in my 2 bedroom apartment."*

In these cases there are so much more information that needs to be taken into account. I just care about how many people will stay, which animals will stay is just noise. And if they will stay in their friend´s place I need to extract that info so I can take some action in my bot. The problem is that there are endless of variations of how the user can reply to the bot´s question in this situation.

I have gone through all the LUIS documentation on Microsofts site, however it only covers very simple utterances, so I dont find much guidance there.

I have made my best try to put this up in LUIS. See the pictures below (Here I use 1 Simple Enttiy and 7 Roles).

[image]
[image]

i´m not sure if this is the correct approach? I´m I really supposed to label every word with a enttiy as I am doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of suggestions:

1. No you do not need to label every word in an utterance with an entity. You should only label the significant parts such as the number of people, how many rooms there are, and the accommodation type. From these you an infer and relay to the user information e.g. if you're using `Accomodation:AmountPersons` then you know you're talking about people, so you only need to extract the number, not the subject and action.
2. Investigate [patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-how-to-model-intent-pattern) to simplify your variations.
3. Start simple then build on what you have later:

   - I don't know if in your scenario that additional "beings" such as pets is critical but I would start by stripping it right back to only supporting the base scenario - which is people staying.
   - Is the room type critical for your scenario? Presumably people are booking a room rather than sleeping on a couch. ;-) Again I would just go with accomodation type (apartment, cottage etc).
   - Break up your bot's question into two parts - first ask how many people are staying, then where they are staying. This will make your life easier in terms of adding utterances and patterns, again you can build on this functionality later if you want to support users entering one line.

I'm not sure if LUIS alone is the best tool for this, the Bot Framework supports dialogs and [waterfall dialogs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-dialog-manage-conversation-flow?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) seem perfect for what you want. There is a sample project available in [C#](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/05.multi-turn-prompt) and [NodeJS](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/05.multi-turn-prompt) which should give you something to build from.